# Rails filtering resource one to many through a joint table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following resources:
- restaurant
- category
- item
- check item

Relationship:

```
class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
  has_many :categories
  has_many :check_items

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :restaurant
  has_many :items

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :restaurant
  belongs_to :category

class CheckItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
```

I need to filter all the check_items of a restaurant `where category.uuid = '123123'`

so I have my `@restaurant.check_items`. How do I join these together to basically implement this sql query:

```
SELECT * from checkitem
INNER JOIN item ON(checkitem.item_id = item.id)
INNER JOIN category ON(category.id = item.category_id)
WHERE category.restaurant_id = 1 AND category.uuid = '123123'
LIMIT 20;
```

I've tried with scope:

```
#already have my restaurant resource here with id 1
@restaurant.check_items.by_item_category params[:category_uuid]
```

And in my models I would have:

```
class CheckItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  scope :by_item_category, -> value { joins(:item).by_category value }

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  scope :by_category, -> value { joins(:category).where('%s.uuid = ?' % Category.table_name, value)}
```

Buut this doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be the only way I found this to be working if anyone is interested.

CheckItem.joins(:item => {:category => :restaurant}).where('category.uuid=? and restaurant.id=?', 123123, 1)